# Search Integration in Java Web Application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts2, hibernate-search

I want to integrate search in my struts + spring + hibernate web appliaction
Which is the best and also lightweight open source solution for doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate search is one option else you can always go for Apache Solr  [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

i will prefer Solr since its an implementation above Apache Lucene and is much faster more flexible and user friendly as well with a good community to support.Additionally its being used is many large scale projects with success rates

Comment: Are there any examples available for Solr particularly with Spring/Hibernate..or is it easier to integrate with them

Comment: Its easier to integrate it comes with multiple data handler which are capable of handling and indexing any type of data just go to the Solr web page and you will get a start up guide.Solr work independently as it tend to index data and all search will be executed inside the index you can configure Solr where it should go to index data like database,file system, web or any other resource

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried hibernate search?

Comment: No I have not tried it, but does it support searching files which are not stored in database